# CiviCRM Recurring Contributions Report with Campaign

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, reports

I'm trying to find a way to get a report on all the Recurring Contributions and what campaign they are attached too. Has anyone else done this? The Recurring Contributions report can give me the donations but there is no Campaign column.
[image: d]
Thanks

Comment: So I was able to get the Campaign Id by changing the Recur.php file but I could only add campign_id. I would say I need to somehow do a join with the civicrm_campaign table to get the campaign title. Does anyone know the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add this to the bottom of the alterDisplay in the Recur.php file to change the Campaign Id to the Campaign Title.
[image]

Comment: Maybe I should submit this change to CiviCRM core? I think it would be beneficial to others

Comment: Have you looked into ReportPlus yet? I'm sure that would allow you to specify, for example financial type and campaign and then filter for only recurring ones.